# Why am I getting the wrong datetime format in my GUI?

Tags: java, swing, parsing, calendar, simpledateformat

I am working on a client server application, whereby the server sends some stuff to the client  and the client can see the items which is displayed in a GUI.
I can send everything perfectly from the server to be displayed at the JTextarea in the client side. However, One problem that I am facing is displaying the date in the client, I am getting a long text which looks like this java.util.Gregeon CalenderCalender[time?= etc..... in the textarea of the GUI. After all the text I can still see the date right at the bottom of the textarea but it is not in the correct format.

This is the part of code in the client side that deals with accepting information from  the server and displaying the info onto the GUI.

```
        public void  displayItems() 
{
    Integer itemNumber = networkInput.nextInt();
    networkInput.nextLine();
    //String bidTime = networkInput.next();
    //= networkInput.next();

    DefaultListModel<String> lmdl = new DefaultListModel<String>();

    for(int i=0; i<itemNumber; i++)
    {
        String itemCode = networkInput.nextLine();
        String itemName = networkInput.nextLine();
        String itemDescription = networkInput.nextLine();
        String date = networkInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println(date);
        int hrs = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0,2));
        int mins = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3,5));
        Items item = new Items(itemCode,itemName,itemDescription, hrs, mins);
        itemList.add(item);

        lmdl.addElement(item.getItemCode());


    }
    ItemList.setModel(lmdl);// Add to List


}
   class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener 
   {
       private Object sel;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            int selectedIx = ItemList.getSelectedIndex();
            String bid = txtBidAmount.getText();
            System.out.println("Sending the bid for " + itemList.get(selectedIx).getItemCode() + " for " + bid);

            output.println("bid");
            output.println(itemList.get(selectedIx).getItemCode());
            output.println(bid);

            String serverResponce = networkInput.nextLine();
            System.out.println(serverResponce);
            if(serverResponce.contains("success"))
            {
                //display sucess
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Bid accepted");
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"low bid");
            }


        }
   }

  class  RefreshListner implements ListSelectionListener{
     //String date = networkInput.nextLine();
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {

        Integer IDx = ItemList.getSelectedIndex();
        text.setText(itemList.get(IDx).getName()+ "\n" + itemList.get(IDx).getDescription() + itemList.get(IDx).getDeadline());


    }


  }
```

}

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 2):

The `toString` method of GregorianCalendar does not produce a display friendly time string. You need to use a DateFormatter to transform it into a more 'pleasant' format before setting it to your  text area. Heres a simple example you can extend:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: but I have converted to a String already from my server side, and I have tested it by printing it to the console which looks perfectly fine.

Comment: You might want to double check the sending part of your server code then, because that output you showed definitely comes from the `toString` method of GregorianCalendar.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you take just time from input string:

```
String date = networkInput.nextLine();
int hrs = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0,2));
int mins = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3,5));
```

Looks like you have in your input line something like "10:39" - parse complete date (with day, month and year) and create Calendar object:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm");
Date date = df.parse(networkInput.nextLine());
```

Then use date object, you can use from it just time if you want.